# Drawing a custom progressbar inside of a listview row column?

Tags: c#, listview, drawing, progress-bar

So I am currently making a program the uploads files and I am displaying the upload progress and details in a Windows Forms ListView component with 3 columns:

- Filename
- To
- Progress

I want to draw a ProgressBar component inside of the third column to show the current progress of the upload instead of just having a text form of say "5%". Here is my code for displaying the upload details:

```
foreach (Uploader up in Uploads)
{
    if (!up.Bdone)
    {
        int progress = up.progress; //current progress
        //this is where I want to draw progressbar inside row column
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        to_remove.Add(up);
    }
}
```

Comment: Winforms and default.

Comment: Can you also answer my first question?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything as when I searched around I couldn't find any great examples of implementing this.

Comment: It isn't very hard, type "listview progress bar winforms" and out comes this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/af368c81-cb38-4934-b289-01f6413ab569/